# javascript split and JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, split

I want to parse array in JSON format using javascript. I have written following code.

```
var data = "abc, xyz, pqr";
var data_array = data.split(',');

var data_parsed = JSON.parse(data_array);
alert(data_parsed);
```

It gives me the error of JSON.parse
I have no idea how to resolve this javascript error.

Comment: always worth a look. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have any JSON, so don't use JSON.parse. Once you split you already have an array whose elements could be used directly:

```
var data = "abc, xyz, pqr";
var data_array = data.split(',');
alert(data_array[0]);
```

and if you want to convert this array to a JSON string you could do this:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data_array);
alert(json);
```

Comment: +1 very true. also alert(data == JSON.parse(json)) will be true only.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `"abc, xyz, pqr"` isn't valid JSON. Plus, `JSON.parse()` is meant to parse JSON strings, not arrays. What are you trying to do, perhaps we can better assist.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a convenient short cut to json processing if you only need a smaller set of variables.

PHP:

```
return $var1 .','. $var2 .',some_string_value.';
```

Javascript:

```
var myReturnArray = returnValue.split(',');
```